# Append Custom Object in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, class, object

I'm curious if it's possible to "append" a custom class object? I've created an object that is intended to be updated somewhat frequently and for readability purposes, it would be nice to do the following:

```
Dim nwObject As New CustomObject
nwObject += anotherCustomObject
nwObject += yetAnotherCustomObject
'' ... So on and so forth
```

I've started overriding the `ToString()` function already, so is there a similar process to allowing this sort of functionality?

### Edit

Forgot to mention that the `anotherCustomObject` and `yetAnotherCustomObject` are defined "children" of the `nwObject` class. Currently there is already a series of overloaded functions that allow "appending" the `nwObject` with multiple, well-defined objects in a well-handled function. The functions look similar to the following:

```
Public Overloads Sub AppendObject(ByVal aObject As AnotherObject)
  '' Use the correct properties to append the base class properties
End Sub
Public Overloads Sub AppendObject(ByVal yaObject As YetAnotherObject)
  '' Use the correct properties to append the base class properties
End Sub
```

(That was off the top of my head, so please forgive basic mistakes. You should get the picture ;) )

Comment: how would that work if more than one had a method named `Save` or a property named `Name`?  Which one is used?

Comment: I see your point, and I forgot to mention that the other objects are defined and the current method involves using an overloaded sub to "append" the `nwObject`

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by append because most likely "+" would be an undefined operator for the Type.  This is likely an XY problem looking for something like private/helper classes

Comment: @Plutonix That's kind of what I'm asking, whether it's possible to define a way to allow the "+" operator to be used instead of the `AppendObject` method I added to the base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I was looking for on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scs11cxx.aspx) MSDN page. Turns out I need to Override the "+" operator function just like I did with the `ToString()` function. Here's the code I used (using the example in the question):

```
Public Overloads Shared Operator +(ByVal nwObject As CustomObject,ByVal aObject As AnotherObject) As CustomObject
  nwObject.MainProperty = nwObject.MainProperty.Replace("Some String",aObject.SpecificProperty)
  Return nwObject
End Operator
Public Overloads Shared Operator +(ByVal nwObject As Custom Object, ByVal yaObject As YetAnotherObject) As CustomObject
  nwObject.MainProperty = nwObject.MaintProperty.Replace("Some String",yaObject.AnotherSpecificProperty)
  Return nwObject
End Operator
```